# View hidden directories in "Browse Data Directory" Diagnostic TeamCity feature

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

TeamCity has a diagnostic feature called "Browse Data Directory". It's pretty useful since my TC setup prohibits me from logging directly to the server. Unfortunately I have noticed that directories beginning with "." are not displayed in the tree. Is there any way to enable this via internal property?

Answer (score 1):

The feature [was added](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-45201) in TeamCity 10.0 EAP2 version, which is going to be released next week.